# angular build Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

Everything is working fine in my local with .net mvc and angular.
Build is also fine `ng build --prod`
When it is published to Azure Webapp gives following error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined
at Object.se (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:111)
at angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:112
at Module.zUnb (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:112)
at l (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:107)
at Object.0 (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:112)
at l (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:107)
at t (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:107)
at Array.r [as push] (angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:107)
at angularscripts?v=nb9jsHHTzj94tWM8v3o1HKlnIfKc4GhJt4hIB2GBemc1:112
```

Comment: is your production build also working locally?

Comment: Yes working fine in local